# Add New Entry and Gives Automatic Background Color

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Is it possible in Google Sheet, that every time I add a new entry in sheet1 column A, it would have a background color not the same with the previous entries? And in sheet2, column D, if the entry was added, it will get the background color that it has in sheet1?

How can I do it in app script?

Comment: Every time I need to add a new client name in Clients tab column A, it will automatically have a background color, and if I added a task in the Tasks tab, it will get the background color from the Clients tab.

here is a working file I am working on:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tKfA_Y0TvYliq9Hc9z01AZ7Lbxb4hnmLbJ1kqa6VIp0/edit#gid=44243712

Comment: yes :) that's correct,

Comment: it should only have one client for the column A of clients tab, just only in the tasks tab would have multiple clients because the data is based on the clients tab..